# After resetting mysql password and forgetting to terminate, mysql worked, but my client could not access, why?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-connector

Running on Popos, a derivative of ubuntu.
I have a mariadb service running successfully. I can connect using the mysql client for either my own id or root from localhost.

I installed:

```
sudo apt install libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

here is the result of apt info:

```
Source: mysql-connector-c++
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian MySQL Maintainers <pkg-mysql-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 2,059 kB
Depends: libboost-dev, libmysqlcppconn7v5 (= 1.1.12-4ubuntu2)
Homepage: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-cpp/en/news-1-1.html
Download-Size: 247 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
Description: MySQL Connector for C++ (development files)
 MySQL Connector/C++ is a MySQL database connector for C++.
 .
 It mimics the JDBC 4.0 API.
 .
 This package contains the development files (headers, static library).
```

At one point, I swear this code ran, but it's just barely possible that I am misremembering it and it ran on another machine.

I had just compiled in many more tests, and now the executable definitely doesn't run, but the other code is irrelevant, because it is dying on the 2nd line, trying to connect to the database.

I verify that the service is up, with:

```
ps -afe | grep mariadb
```

and it is running.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

works, as does

```
mysql -u me -p
```

The code is:

```
try {
Driver* driver = get_driver_instance();
if (driver == nullptr) throw "Could not get driver";

// connect to hardcoded local mysql server
// note: not good practice to embed password in code! just for first demo
Connection* con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "me", "test");
} ...
```

replacing with root doesn't work either

```
Connection* con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "pw here");
```

Either way the error is:

```
# ERR: SQLException in testconnect.cpp(main) on line 113
# ERR: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111) (MySQL error code: 2003,
     SQLState: HY000 )
```

which would seem to indicate that it can't make the connection.

I found the reason. I had forgotten the password and manually had to reset it. In doing so I ran with

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

but it was working with queries from mysql, so how did it know the difference between my code working with my account, and mysql client?

Comment: Do you have an options file in `~/.my.cnf` with the `host` option set, or do you set an environment variable that makes the client connect to a different instance?

Comment: FYI, you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. We should consider these different products, since both have changed significantly since MariaDB forked. They are no longer compatible, or simple variations of the same product.

Comment: @BillKarwin first line says I am running mariadb, and it's in the tags.

Comment: I ran manually as described in order to reset passwords, forgot to kill it and restart. Code didn't work, but mysql -u worked normally so I didn't notice. Once I killed the manually run mariadb and restarted, everything worked. My question is HOW DOES MARIADB know the difference between mysql -u user and my code? this is all on localhost.  I have never created an options file, didn't know about it and did not set up an environment variable. In any case, note that it now works with no change to my setup?

Comment: If you use `mysql --protocol tcp` followed by your other options for user and password,  does it fail?

Comment: @BillKarwin no it doesn't fail, but I brought back the regular service and it now works. So what protocol does mysql use if it isn't tcp?

Comment: By default the client connects using a mechanism called the UNIX domain socket. This is local-only, but a little bit faster than a TCP connection. This is the default, unless you specify the connection via TCP, or if you use `--host` and specify a host other than `localhost`.

Comment: Here's the tricky part: The MariaDB user `root@localhost` is a different user than `root@%` or @ any other specific host or IP address. The different users may have different passwords and different privileges. So if you created one of these users for one protocol, but connected via the other protocol, you find you can't connect with that user, or don't have the privileges you expect.

Comment: The MariaDB manual does a very bad job at explaining this.